# How can I disable missed call notifications on iOS 12?

Tags: ios, notifications, phone.app

If I miss a call where no message is left, I don't want to know about it. How can I disable notifications for missed calls without disabling notifications for voicemail messages?

Answer (score 1):

Turning off badge notifications for the Phone app will stop the number of missed calls from showing on the app icon while preserving voicemail notifications.

Settings -> Notifications -> Phone -> Turn off Badges

Comment: But won't I still get a banner notification when I miss a call? And won't this also suppress a badge showing new voicemail messages?

Comment: Correct, this would turn off badges for all Phone.app notifications. There is no other way to selectively target Phone BANNER notifications, so it may be worth checking out WhatsApp